# Overcome z-index stacking

Tags: css, z-index

I've been experimenting with this for over a week and I'm about to give up, as I think this is not possible, but I wanted to reach out to this awesome community first.

What I'm trying to achieve is to, somehow, overcome the stacked z-index settings.

Let me show you an example so you maybe get the idea faster:

http://raulmellado.com/clientes/zindextest/

What I'd like is to have the green div (#shouldbeontop) on top of all elements (I am setting it to position:fixed).

In other responses in stackoverflow (yes I've read dozens of threads here), the answer is to change the html, move elements around, etc, but my problem is that I'm creating the #shouldbeontop and #scrollbar elements dynamically using js (my application is a bit more complex than this example, but I've tried to simplify to share my problem here).

I've created a js that can be embedded (ideally) on any webpage which will add the elements, so I can use js if needed, but I can just assume that the #shouldbeontop and #scrollbar elements will be there; the rest could be any html/css combination that's already there.

Usually, where there is no z-index in different divs, this works beautifully, but as soon as there is some stacking, it breaks :-(

If you would like to see a real life application of this, here you can find a quick & dirty demo: http://videngage.me/demo/demo1.html   (here there is no z-index, so the video [#shouldbeontop in my simplified demo] is always shown on top (when you scroll down), but here http://www.members.skolahudbyonline.eu/rytmus-trening-majstra/ the video goes behind when you scroll down)

Is there an universal solution for this (using css and/or js), or should I just give up?

Thanks sooooooooo much for your help

Comment: AFAIK you won't get around rearranging your html. Your `#shouldbeontop` should be appended to the body directly. `position: fixed` does create a new stacking context, but only for its child-elements.

Comment: You have to rearrange your elements. If the elements are on the same "plain", then that's where `z-index` comes into play with those "sibling" elements.  Other than that, why don't you just remove the `z-index and position` from `#content2`?

Comment: Hi, thank you both for your answers. I don't have control over things like content1/content2 (I added these as a quick and dirty example, but in real life it could be anything). My js code will add the equivalent of #shouldbeontop, and it needs to be exactly there (as a child), as it will be a video that needs to go in that position. So the short answer is, this is not possible using just css and js, without rearranging elements, right? I could of course move it inside the dom, but the video will stop playing when I do that :-( Thanks anyway!

Comment: `as it will be a video that needs to go in that position` It is position fixed, so why does it need to be a child of `content1`? I'm not quite following...

Comment: Hi NIls, it is because the video comes from a js embed code that does a document.write, which writes the video html + the scrollbar, and this can be embedded in any web page. When the user scrolls down, the video becomes position:fixed as you can see here: http://videngage.me/demo/demo1.html  but if the user does not scroll, that video needs to be there. Also, I cannot clone nor move the video inside the dom as it will stop playing when scrolling... I can use js and css, but I cannot move elements inside the dom... I guess there is nothing to do then, thanks anyway!